# T-SQL not equal operator vs Case statement

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

Assume I have a T-SQL statement:

```
select * from MyTable
where Code != 'RandomCode'
```

I've been tasked with making this kind of where statement perform more quickly.  Books Online says that positive queries (=) are faster than negative (!= , <>).

So, one option is make this into a CASE statement e.g.

```
select * from MyTable
where 
   case when Code = 'RandomCode' then 0 
      else 1 end = 1
```

Does anyone know if this can be expected to be faster or slower than the original T-SQL ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I fail to see how != would be slower than =, other than having 1 extra char of overhead in the parser. In the end, at the cpu level, it's all a single `cmp`-type instruction with a `jmp/je/jne` jump afterwards. If that 1 byte does make a huge difference to your code, then whatever you're doing is way above the level of this site.

Comment: Use query plan analyzer to check, or profiler.

Comment: I very much agree with both sentiments above.  That said, the `CASE` option looks overly complicated.  Conditional where clauses should be avoided, because they can splinter the query plan (not in this case - no pun intended).

Comment: @MarcB - equality operator can be optimized with an index seek whereas inequality could only be evaluated with table/index scans. The CASE statement is essentially the same as the inequality operator, just more verbose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to be more specific at what information you are interested in the table and what are the possible values of the `Code` column. Then you can create appropriate indexes to speed up the query.

For example, if values in the `Code` column could only be one of `'RandomCode'`, `'OtherCode'`, `'YetAnotherCode'`, you can re-write the query as:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Code = 'OtherCode' OR Code = 'YetAnotherCode'
```

And of course you need an index on the `Code` column.

If you have to do an inequality query, you can change `SELECT *` to a more narrow query like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE Code != 'RandomCode'
```

Then create an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Code ON MyTable(Code) INCLUDE (Id,Name,Whatever)
```

This can reduce I/O by replacing a table scan with an index scan.